# метод для UISegmentedPanel

Tags: ios

У меня есть UISegmentedPanel с двумя елементами я написал метод:

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlValueChanged:(id)sender {

    if (_isCegmentedControlChanged == YES) {
        _isCegmentedControlChanged = NO;
        NSLog(@"value 0");
    }
    else

    _isCegmentedControlChanged = YES;
    NSLog(@"value 1");
```

но работает не правильно, выводит в NSLog одно значение при нажатии на первый елемент, и два значения при нажатии на второй.

Помогите исправить мою ошибку, спасибо.

Comment: предположу, что проблема в отсутствии скобок в else - таким образом второй NSLog вызывается в обоих случаях

Comment: большое спасибо, действительно в этом проблема, не заметил, у меня еще такой вопрос: правильно ли я написал метод для SegmentedControlValueChanged?

Comment: я бы предложил проверять индекс выбранного сегмента `self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex` и на основании этих данных производить нужные действия

Comment: Извините но я не совсем понял как это реализовать

Comment: может я вас не понял. что конкретно этот метод делает?

Comment: ну мне нужно чтобы оно переходило при нажатии из одного segment на другой, я попробовал так:
if (_minuteSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        
    }
    
  if (_minuteSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

    }

но кажется это не правильно

Comment: что то я еще больше запутался. я предполагаю, что в вопросе опечатка и мы ведем речь о `UISegmentedControl`. Чтобы он при нажатии переходил на другой сегмент ничего делать не надо - нажали на сегмент, он подсветился.

Comment: да именно о нем (опечатка)

не надо никакого метода писать для IBAction?

Comment: UISegmentedControl сам меняет себя в зависимости от выбранного элемента - тут ничего добавлять не надо. IBAction нужен, если вам надо мгновенно отреагировать на это изменение, например если в зависимости от выбранного элемента на экране должны появляться разные опции.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а каким свойством передать делегату текущий сегмент?

Comment: для получения информации об изменении текущего сегмента используйте `[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` и уже в нем смотрите новое положение `self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`